# django admin, displaying all instances of a model1 associated with model2 on model2's change page?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, models

Consider these two models `Keyword` and `Statement` (model1 and model2 respectively):

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Keyword(models.Model):
   word      = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   statement = models.ManyToManyField(Statement)
   def __str__(self):
      return self.word

@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Statement(models.Model):
    statement_id = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    issue_date = models.DateField("Issue-Date")
    author = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    released_by = models.ForeignKey(Organization)
    kicpairs = models.ManyToManyField('KeywordInContext')
```

So on the admin site right now, the only way one would be able to determine what keywords are associated with each statement is that they have to go check the `Keyword` model in admin, and check each Keyword's display page and scroll through the menu.

At least with regards to the admin site, it's important for someone to be able to see a `Statement` model's display with all of its associated `Keywords` visible, and for users to be able to choose additional `Keyword`s within the database (or make new ones). I also hope to be able to have a Statement's keywords modifiable on the admin page via the filter_horizontal widget, since that seems to be the most user friendly.

But I'm having trouble just starting with that. I'm not sure what I need to use or how.

Comment: See [Inline model admins](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin)

Comment: I just made a question about this but how do I apply filter_horizontal to an inline model on admin? I syntactically can't seem to do it.